# Verifying rebalancing of unbalanced binary class Caret R

Tags: r, unbalanced-classes, caret

Still very new to R and have only enough statistical knowledge to be dangerous. But I'm stuck as to whether the following is acheiving what I need it to do.

Project is a flight risk prediction using imbalanced population data of 2,227 Leavers and 14,504 Stayers. I want to reserve a balanced set as my test set and set up the training set so it can cross-validate the remaining predicted class against a cross fold of similar numbers of Stayers.  I have decided to use down-sampling as the data is related to actual people and imputation and up-sampling do not support the outcome I hope to acheive both now and in the future.

Unfortunately, after the model runs, the summary sample sizes are in the 13,000's and not around 1327 as I expected which is the size of the remainder of my predictive class after I set aside the test set. The mention of down-sampling seems to be an after the fact.
Is my model cross folding the majority class and balancing it with the train set predicted class?  If not, what else do I need to do in my code to acheive this outcome?

```
'data.frame':   16731 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ fr     : Factor w/ 2 levels "Leave","Stay": 2 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 2 ...
 $ var1   : int  40 50 23 36 52 52 45 44 51 63 ...
 $ var2   : num  19.5 25.8 2.6 12.4 2.4 27 12.8 5.8 1.2 25.7 ...
 $ var4   : int  4 3 3 2 4 3 3 3 4 3 ...
 $ var3   : int  7 7 7 2 2 5 1 6 12 6 ...
 $ var5   : Factor w/ 9 levels "Sec1","Sec2",..: 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ var6   : Factor w/ 6 levels "C","Q","S","T",..: 3 3 5 4 5 6 3 3 3 3 ...


set.seed(42)

n <- nrow(mydata)
shuffled <- mydata[sample(n),]
#want to reserve 900 of each bianry flight risk factor - fr - for the test set
test.rows <- tapply(1:nrow(shuffled), shuffled$fr, sample, size = 900)
tr <- unlist( test.rows )

test <- shuffled[ tr , ]
train <- shuffled[ -tr , ]

ctrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", 
                     number = 10, 
                     repeats = 10,
                     classProbs = TRUE,
                     summaryFunction = twoClassSummary,
                     sampling = "down")

set.seed(5627)
model <- caret::train(fr ~ .,
                        data = train,
                        method = "rpart1SE",
                        metric = "ROC",
                        trControl = ctrl)


model_under_Tree


CART 

14931 samples
    7 predictor
    2 classes: 'Leave', 'Stay' 

No pre-processing
Resampling: Cross-Validated (10 fold, repeated 10 times) 
Summary of sample sizes: 13439, 13439, 13438, 13437, 13437, 13437, ... 
Addtional sampling using down-sampling

#I am also running the model as a glm.
```

Is the code I've written doing what I want it to do? Cross-folding and cross-validating the majority class against the minority predicted class? 
I don't want to run the test set against the model until I know it's doing what I think it needs to do to be as accurate as possible.